# Trouble loading sprite from spritesheet with Phaser

Tags: javascript, sprite, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am working on re-creating a breakout clone to help me learn Phaser (following the overall design of jsbreakouts.org). Anyway, I have the start screen set up. From the start screen, I can transition to the game state without any problems. In my game state, I can load the background and the paddle without issues. The paddle responds to mouse input as it is supposed to.

But the ball does not load for some reason. The ball is coming from a spritesheet. Each ball in the sheet is 16x16 and there are 5 of them. I can't even get one of them to load, let alone animate them.

The balls spritesheet is in the same directory as the paddle. I have looked at other code online and as far as I can tell, I'm doing it right. Yet, it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my game state code:

```
var paddle;
var ball;

var Game = {


preload : function() {
        // Here we load all the needed resources for the level.
        game.load.image('background', './assets/bg_prerendered.png');
        game.load.image('paddle',     './assets/paddle2.png');
        game.load.spritesheet('ballsheet', './assets/balls.png', 16, 16, 5);
        game.load.spritesheet('tiles', './assets/tile_spritesheet.png', 32, 16);
    },

create : function() {
    //enable physics
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    game.physics.arcade.checkCollision.down = false;

    //add the background
    background = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');

    //add score text placeholder
    game.add.text(50, 390, "Lives: 3    Score: 700   Level: 1", { font: "12px sans-serif", fill: "#000000"});

    //add the paddle and set it up
    paddle = game.add.sprite(136, 384, 'paddle');

    //set the anchor to be the lower center of the paddle
    paddle.anchor.set(0.5,1);

    //enable paddle physics
    game.physics.enable(paddle, Phaser.Physics.Arcade);
    paddle.body.immovable = true;
    paddle.body.collideWorldBounds = true;


    ball = game.add.sprite(100,100, 'ballsheet');
    ball.frame = 0;
    //ball.animations.add('rotate',[0,1,2,3,4], 10, true);
    //game.physics.enable(ball, Phaser.Physics.Arcade);
    //ball.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    //ball.play('rotate');

},
    update: function() {
        paddle.x = game.input.x;

    },
};
```

Comment: dont know much about phaser but I noticed you didnt set the anchor to the ball but you did the paddle. I also had trouble when i used phaser of spacing for my spritesheet so it would try to load space between my sprites which looked like nothing to me. I had to fiddle with the size and spacing until i saw part of a leg and went from there

Comment: @Ian The anchor shouldn't matter as it should just default (to top left I assume). I just tested it to confirm it did not matter. Your tip about the sprite sheet is interesting. Hard to imagine that would make a difference, but I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: You could set the frame for a sprite as you create it, `game.add.sprite(100,100, 'ballsheet', 0)` although you can also set the frame later, so that shouldn't really matter. I can't see anything wrong with your code. Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: yea i assumed it had a default but i wasnt sure. Like i said i dont know much and used it forever ago but i remember i had an issue with the spritesheet loading after i resized something and it turned out to be trying to load the background because resizing made the sprite HUGEEE so there was more space than it thought in between. Good luck

Comment: Do you see something at position 100, 100 ? or nothing at all ?

Answer (score 0):

I went back through some games I made and the only thing different between my code and yours is when you declare the spritesheet.

You declare your ball spritesheet:

```
game.load.spritesheet('ballsheet', './assets/balls.png', 16, 16, 5);
```

I do not think you need the 5 at the end. You can just tell Phaser the width and height of each sprite, and it will automatically split it into the correct number of sprites, assuming there is no gap between the sprites on the spritesheet.

You seem to have done it this way when loading your tiles spritesheet. You just declared the width and height of each tile, and didn't need to specify how many sprites are in your spritesheet.

This is the only thing I can think of that might be causing the issue.

I hope it helps you in some way.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Texture Atlases over Spritesheets. They offer better performance and are easier to use, as you don't need to deal with setting the frame dimension nonsense.

[What is Texture Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas)

[Create Texture Atlas](https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/)

[Preloading Texture Atlas (actually any Phaser assets)](https://github.com/rblopes/generator-phaser-plus/blob/master/generators/app/templates/src/assets.js)

`var s = new Sprite(game, 'key', 'frame')`